# Struts 2 setter unknown field parameters

Tags: error-handling, struts2, ognl

My struts 2 (2.3.1) application at debug mode for url `http://localhost/app/check.action?13239 raises such kind of exceptions`

```
2011-12-15 14:45:06,455 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:68] : Setting static parameters {}
2011-12-15 14:45:06,456 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:68] : Setting params NONE
2011-12-15 14:45:06,456 DEBUG [CommonsLogger.java:68] : Setting params 13239 => [  ]
2011-12-15 14:45:06,461 WARN  [CommonsLogger.java:60] : Error setting expression '13239' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@33b4450e'
ognl.InappropriateExpressionException: Inappropriate OGNL expression: 13239
        at ognl.SimpleNode.setValueBody(SimpleNode.java:312)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:220)
        at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:301)
```

I was expecting silently ignoring them according to documentation. What is the correct way to fix this problem?

By the way it seems that struts looking for a setter field for the value `13239` however I guess that it is not suitable for a property which is started by a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is more or less a issue of your personal taste.Sometime we wants to know any time a parameter is submitted that doesn't have a matching getter/setter on the action and its a common use case in development our application and we forget a getter/setter on an action, we want to know about any possible error case.

One possible way to is setting the logging level differently from dev to production.There was a long discussion about this on Struts2 mailing list here is the link for same

[OgnlValueStack Error setting expression warnings after upgrade from struts 2 to struts 2.1.7](http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/S2-OgnlValueStack-Error-setting-expression-warnings-after-upgrade-from-struts-2-to-struts-2-1-7-td3495667.html)

Comment: But for the url `http://localhost/app/check.action?a13239`, it does not raise an error. Why? Note that `a` before 13239